# Display y-axis as percentages?

Tags: javascript, svg, format, d3.js

I'm making a chart, and I want my y-axis tick labels to display as percentages (instead of decimals). How can I do this?

My current code looks something like

```
yAxis
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "ticklabel")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", y)
  .attr("dy", ".5em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(y.tickFormat(5))
  .attr("font-size", "10px")
```

I noticed that d3 has a [format specifier](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#wiki-d3_format), but I'm not sure how to use these in conjunction with `tickFormat`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It looks like you authoring the axis by hand. I recommend using the [d3.svg.axis](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes) component instead, which does the rendering for you. For example:

- http://bl.ocks.org/1166403

If you want to format ticks as percentages, then use [d3.format](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#wiki-d3_format)'s *%* directive:

```
var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent);
```

You can instead use the *p* directive if you want to round to the percentage to significant digits.

To answer your question more directly, you use d3.format *instead of* the scale's tickFormat. Scales provide a default tickFormat for convenience, but if you want different behavior, then you use a custom d3.format rather than the scale's default one.

Comment: When I try to use `d3.format(".0%");` it gives me tick values in % format but value changes. Original tick values were [-25,-20,-15,-10,-5,0,5,10,15,20] after using this solution, [-2500%,-2000%,-1500%,-1000%,-500%,0%,500%,1000%,1500%,2000%]

Comment: @HirdeshVishwdewa - Make sure to use decimal values like 0.25, 0.44, 0.6 to avoid them being converted to incorrect percentage values.